# How to use buttons to add models to a three js scene?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, three.js

I have a three.js scene. I want to create a game where if I click a button, it adds a cube to some random location and it repeats that action whenever I click that button. I am currently using react with three.js (not react three fiber). Can someone please give me any idea of how to achieve that because I am clueless:(

I tried making a base scene and I am using `useEffect` and `useState`, but i am not confident about it.

Comment: Why this aversion to R3F, if I may ask? _...but i am not confident about it."_ - I think you will have an easier time with R3F...